# Output HTML template with C# or MVC

Tags: templates, content-management-system, tags

I've looked around the web for a guide on how to get C# to output an HTML-file.
I also need to be able to deploy self-defined tags in the HTML-file, which should output data from the SQL.

Is there anyone who can give an example, or know of a tutorial?

Basically I'm trying to develope a simple CMS, in which the user can upload a html-file, and then define dynamic content using pre-defined tags in the html-file, like @Header, @Text etc.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you found on the internet that you have rejected? It looks like any half friendly xml generating library will do the trick unless there's something I'm missing?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. What I've come across, is that MVC 3 + Razor, would be the right approach to develope a simple CMS, like the one I'm thinking of.

I just need a tutorial which explains how templates and self-defined template tags are working.